The product of two periodic matrix valued functions
Some background:

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ be a map. We say that $f$ is periodic if there exists a real number $T > 0$ such that $f(t+T) = f(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. In this case, we say that $T$ is a period of $f$.
If $f$ is continuous, non-constant and periodic, then there exists a smallest period $T_f$, which we call the fundamental period. Every other period of $f$ is a positive integer multiple of $T_f$.
We say that two non-zero real numbers $a,b \in \mathbb R$ are commensurable if $a/b$ is a rational number.

I am trying to prove the following proposition, but I am stuck.
Proposition. Let $P,Q:\mathbb R \rightarrow \text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ be non-constant, continuous, and periodic maps. Then the product $PQ:\mathbb R \rightarrow \text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ is periodic if and only if the fundamental periods of $P$ and $Q$ are commensurable.
Proof attempt. Let $T_P$ and $T_Q$ denote the fundamental periods of $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Suppose $T_P$ and $T_Q$ are commensurable. Then there exist positive integers $k,l$ such that $kT_P = l T_Q$. Then it is straightforward to check that $T := kT_P = l T_Q$ is a period of $PQ$.
Conversely, suppose $PQ:\mathbb R \rightarrow \text{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$ is periodic. If $PQ$ is constant $PQ \equiv A$, then $Q(t) = P(t)^{-1}A$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, so it follows that $T_P = T_Q$.
Suppose $PQ$ is not constant. Then $PQ$ has a fundamental period $T > 0$. Then $P(t+T) Q(t+T) = P(t) Q(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, so
$$P(t)^{-1}P(t+T) = Q(t+T)^{-1}Q(t) \quad \forall t \in \mathbb R.$$
Define $\gamma:\mathbb R \rightarrow \text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ by $\gamma(t) := P(t)^{-1}P(t+T)$. It is straightforward to show that $T_P$ and $T_Q$ are periods of $\gamma$. If $\gamma$ is not constant, then $T_P$ and $T_Q$ are integer multiples of the fundamental period of $\gamma$, so $T_P$ and $T_Q$ are commensurable.
Here is where I am stuck. How do I handle the case where $\gamma$ is constant?

Notice that since $c = P(t)^{-1}P(t+T)$, $P(t)c^n = P(t+nT)$. If $nT = T_P$, then $c^n = I$.
